# Replacing the for loop with the while loop

Tags: c++, loops

I have the following piece of code:

```
for (bool &flag : allFlags) {
    flag = true;
}
```

I got an assignment to replace the `for` loop with the `while` loop. But because of the reference `&flag`, I'm not sure how to achieve it. It is very basic and I'm a bit ashamed to ask. But I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: How would you do it if there wasn't a reference?

Comment: Every object that can be iterated with the ranged-for loop must satisfy a number of requirements, which let the compiler automagically generate the code needed for iteration. You can read all about it [in here](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ranged), and write your code based on that information.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it simply like this, but such replacement is silly:

```
{
 auto ptr=allFlags.begin();
 auto end=allFlags.end();

 while( ptr!=end ) { *ptr=true; ++ptr; }
}
```

Comment: `allFlags` is an array. It does not have `begin` and `end` though. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: That won't work if `allFlags` is a raw array.

Comment: You can use `std::begin(allFlags)` and `std::end(allFlags)`.

Answer (score 1):

## General

The iterators may be used to operate upon (and, in particular, iterate over) the «raw» array.

As [@DimChtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6084430/dimchtz) has mentioned, to get the begin iterator and the end iterator, it is necessary to use the [`std::begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) functions correspondingly.

Below two alternative approaches are presented.

## Using `std::fill()` (recommended)

Please, consider using the [`std::fill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) function, since it does exactly what is required.

Here is an example program:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    bool allFlags[] = { true, false, true, false };
    auto begin = std::begin(allFlags);
    auto end = std::end(allFlags);

    // Updating the element values.
    std::fill(begin, end, true);

    // Printing the element values.
    std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<bool>(std::cout, " "));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

## `while` loop (as per original request, without using `std::fill()`)

Here is an example program:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    bool allFlags[] = { true, false, true, false };
    auto begin = std::begin(allFlags);
    auto end = std::end(allFlags);

    // The loop to update the element values.
    auto it = begin;
    while (it != end) {
        auto& element = *it;

        // Updating the element value.
        element = true;

        ++it;
    }

    // Printing the element values.
    std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<bool>(std::cout, " "));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```